# Toggle an insterted element onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, insert

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".exmore").before("<span class='rmtrail'>...</span>");

    $(document).on("click",".exmore", function(e){
      console.log("clicked");
      console.log($(this).siblings("rmtrail").html());
      $(this).siblings("rmtrail").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href='#' class='exmore'>open</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to toggle the inserted `.rmtrail` element when the `.exmore` element is clicked but the `$(this).siblings();` method is not working. `console.log()` returns undefined.

Is there a way to force the `jQuery` DOM to update after an element is inserted? I have been looking online and can not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rmtrail` is a class so try `.rmtrail`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".exmore").before("<span class='rmtrail'>...</span>");

    $(document).on("click",".exmore", function(e){
      console.log("clicked");
      console.log($(this).siblings(".rmtrail").html());
      $(this).siblings(".rmtrail").toggle();
    });
 });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href='#' class='exmore'>open</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank your for your help! I am very jet lagged today!